# PHP different results of pg_escape_bytea() when connecting to postgresql

Tags: php, postgresql

Code:

```
echo pg_escape_bytea(45);
```

Result: 
    45

Code:

```
pg_connect ("host=$host dbname=$db user=$user password=$pass");
echo pg_escape_bytea(45);
```

Result: 
    \x3435

I don't want to change the result. How can I do that? 
Please help!

Answer (score 0):

**SHORT ANSWER:**

Never call the `pg_escape_bytea` function before `pg_connect`.

**LONG ANSWER:**

The `pg_escape_bytea` function is charset-aware function.

Function definition:

```
pg_escape_bytea ([ resource $connection ], string $data ) : string
```

As you can see from the funnction definition, you can pass a `$connection` as the first parameter. You can obtain this connection as a result from the `pg_connect` or `pg_pconnect` functions. However, I don't know how to obtain this "connection resource" from a PDO object.

Every connection has a charset associated with it. So when you pass a connection as the first parameter to `pg_escape_bytea` it will "read" the associated charset and encode the result accordingly.

If you don't pass the connection as the first parameter, then the `pg_escape_bytea` function will simply use the latest PostgreSQL connection.

**And here is the problem:**

If you call the `pg_escape_bytea` **before** you connect to your PostgreSQL database (using `pg_connect` or `pg_pconnect` or PDO ...) then the `pg_escape_bytea` function **WILL NOT KNOW** how to encode the result!

If you connect to your database and then call the `pg_escape_bytea` function with the exactly same input data it **may return different output because the charset of the latest PostgreSQL connection changed!**

**SOLUTION:**

So I think the easiest workaround is simply to never call the `pg_escape_bytea` function before `pg_connect` function (or other "connect" functions / PDO) because it will simply doesn't know how to encode the result properly.

PS: If you want to experiment with different outputs, you can change the charset like this:

```
$pdo->query("SET NAMES UTF8")
```

Answer (score -1):

From the manual:

> When you SELECT a bytea type, PostgreSQL returns octal byte values
>   prefixed with '\' (e.g. \032). Users are supposed to convert back to
>   binary format manually.

So after the connection is made, you need to deal with it manually.

Comment: He didn't say he SELECTed something. He just connected to PostgreSQL using pg_connect and the result of "pg_escape_bytea" function changed. I have the exact problem. Can you help?